# Show Hidden Form Field with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I seem to be having an issue with Jquery not displaying a hidden DIV after a selected form value is chosen. When a user clicks yes, I want the hidden div to then be revealed. Am I missing something? You can take a look here https://jsfiddle.net/73merxk9/

#### Javascript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#permit').on('permit', function() {
            $("#hiddenform").toggle($(this).val() == 'Yes');
        }).trigger('permit');
    });
</script>
```

#### Form

```
<div>
    <label for="permit">Permit</label>
    <select id="permit" name="permit">
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="1">Yes</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="hiddenform">
    <div>
        <label for="permit_submitted">Permit Submitted</label>
        <input placeholder="Permit Input Here..." name="job_number" type="text" id="job_number">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such event "permit". You need to listen `onchange` event instead. Then you need to compare select value with `"1"` because `Yes` is a label, not value:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#permit').on('change', function () {
        $("#hiddenform").toggle($(this).val() == '1');
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/73merxk9/1/